# Django Store date only or query with date only

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

My requirement is, every year the post should be found by user with a specific date range. in end_date and state_date

So i want to store only date or i have to query by `date` only instead of `year`

But i found no way to do that, coz, it is storing `year` too

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I have tried to query like this:

```
post = Post.objects.filter(
    start_date__gte='09-16',
    end_date__lte='10-01'
)
```

but above solution doesnt work well, any have ideas how can i do it? storing date only except year or query by date only?, so that it works every year without any hassle

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
post = Post.objects.filter(
    start_date__day__gte=16, start_date__month__gte=9,
    end_date__day__lte=10, end_date__month__lte=1
)
```

Basically, you use `day`, `month` and year with `DateField` and `DateTimeField` the same way you use `eq`, `lt` etx.